# jQuery, Check if image exists returns false negative

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, get

I'm trying to determine if an image exists before inserting it into the site.

I've tried all the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327655/jquery-check-if-image-exists) and all of them return a negative for an image I know exists. For example:

```
$.ajax({
url:'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stuffstory-v2-filepicker/thumbnails/5547b98e357a7f425f8b4570/555340a1357a7f673a8b456b.png',
type:'HEAD',
error:
    function(){
        console.log('No image')
    },
success:
    function(){
        console.log('There is an image')
    }
});
```

Returns a no image result, but when if you follow the link: [Image](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stuffstory-v2-filepicker/thumbnails/5547b98e357a7f425f8b4570/555340a1357a7f673a8b456b.png) It's clearly there.

I am utterly flummoxed as to why.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16596437/1113766

Answer (score 4):

Your cross-domain AJAX request is blocked by `CORS` security policy:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Image` for this:

```
var imageUrl = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stuffstory-v2-filepicker/thumbnails/5547b98e357a7f425f8b4570/555340a1357a7f673a8b456b.png';
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    // will be called if image exists
};
img.onerror = function (){
   // will be called if image failed to download
};
img.src = imageUrl;
```

This way the images can be downloaded cross-domain.
See also [Image on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image).

Comment: Now the existing images show as true, but so do the non-existent images.

I have 9 image spots, 3 with existing images, 6 without. I got 9 positives

Comment: In my tests, if image does not exists, the error callback is triggered. Can you post your attempt?

Comment: Interesting. It seems to work on this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7z8t84fg/, but not on my development site, which is only local so I can't share it.

I am iterating through a number of images, based JSON response, I'm wondering if this could be the problem

Comment: Which browser do you use? And how this is not working? Does it report the non-existing as existing or existing as not existing?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by ***@crashet***

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

For an alternative:

Use `onerror` Event

> Execute a JavaScript if an error occurs when loading an image:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stuffstory-v2-filepicker/thumbnails/5547b98e357a7f425f8b4570/555340a1357a7f673a8b456bewweweg" onerror="imgError()" />
```

**JS:**

```
function imgError()
{
alert('The image could not be loaded.');
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7z8t84fg/)**

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Comment: This is brilliant. And I'm sorry, I should have said, I'm using the image as a background image. Can I apply this to that?

Comment: @PaulAston With background images, there is no event... Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a request that is on different domain from your app thats why it is restricting this. if you will open your console window you will see the error. 
you need to achieve this using cors. reference http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonp requests to load cross domain resources for example image in your case

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
$(function () {
   //Image Error
   $("img").on("error", function () {
     var $img = $(this);
     var imgsrc = $img.attr("src");
     $img.attr("src", "New Image Path");
   });
});
```